# Manipulate string values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with different formats for one column like this

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| First | 5-9 |
| Second | 7 |
| Third | - |
| Fourth | 12-16 |

I need to iterate over all Values column, and if the format is like the first row `5-9` or like fourth row `12-16` replace it with the mean between the 2 numbers in string.
For first row replace `5-9` to `7`, or for fourth row replace `12-16` to `14`.
And if the format is like third row `-` replace it to 0

I have tried

```py
if df["Value"].str.len() > 1:
    df["Value"] = df["Value"].str.split('-')
    df["Value"] = (df["Value"][0] + df["Value"][1]) / 2
elif df["Value"].str.len() == 1:
    df["Value"] = df["Value"].str.replace('-', 0)
```

Expected output

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| First | 7 |
| Second | 7 |
| Third | 0 |
| Fourth | 14 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us `split` and `expand` the column then cast values to `float` and calculate `mean` along column axis:

```
s = df['Values'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df['Values'] = s[s != ''].astype(float).mean(1).fillna(0)
```

---

```
     Name  Values
0   First     7.0
1  Second     7.0
2   Third     0.0
3  Fourth    14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace` with customized replacement function

```py
mint = lambda s: int(s or 0)
repl = lambda m: str(sum(map(mint, map(m.group, [1,2])))/2)
df['Values'] = df['Values'].str.replace('(\d*)-(\d*)', repl, regex=True)
```

```
print(df)

     Name Values
0   First    7.0
1  Second      7
2   Third    0.0
3  Fourth   14.0
```